# How to Custom Tab bar item text

Tags: iphone

I am using five tab bar items in the tab bar,i want to custom the text which is displayed on that.Is it possible.Please help me in this.Thanks in advance

Thanks
ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use IB to do this.click ones on tab bar item and go to its property by command+1 and then again click ones on same tab bar item and you will get property window in which you can change the text of tab bar item...

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a "TabBarItem" in the view controller in each space.

So in the init function for the root view controller of each tab bar item:

```
UIImage* anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabicon.png"];

UITabBarItem* theItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your custom text" image:anImage tag:0];

self.tabBarItem = theItem;

[theItem release];
```

Comment: Thank you for ur reply Thomas,i am getting this.What my actual problem is if the text is large,it is going in one line,i want to show that it in two lines.Is it possible

Comment: oh right... had a quick look on the internet and couldn't find anything. far from creating your own tab bar controller class its going to be very difficult, if not impossible to do this. It would probably be better to just cut down the titles of the tab bar items. Try and get just a one word indicator or something. People don't want to spend too long reading a tab bar item. :)